# City targeting range - Facebook Post API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I'm having trouble sending a parameter for the creation of an Ad through the facebook api, specifically in the targeting (Audience). I'm trying to set the radius in miles around a city of the people I'm trying to target in my ad... According to the spec:

```
  "targeting= { \
       'geo_locations': { \
            'regions': [{'key':'3847'}],\
            'cities': [ \
                {'key':'2430536', \
                 'radius':12, \
                 'distance_unit':'mile'} \
            ] \
       },
        'genders':[1], \
        'relationship_statuses':[2,3,4], \
        'age_min':'18', \
        'age_max':'43', \
        'keywords':['movies']}" \
```

The parameter is "radius" and "distance_unit", i put these parameters in the targeting, create the ad (it creates successfully), but the parameter of radius doesn't persist... I check the Power Editor and the radius doesn't appear!

Can someone help me with some other ideas? Thanks!

Here is the spec page...
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/

Comment: Does it work in the API response when you fetch the ad later? It's not typically supported to create ads in one interface and modify them in another (e.g. create in API and load in power editor)

Comment: It doesn't come the range when i fetch the ad! In the city info, it only shows the id and the name